# How to change hidden-input value then send it using django forms?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I have a problem with Ajax in Django forms, it refuses to change value of a hidden input send the `views.py` class. 
The template `configuration.html` contains a form that selects number of parameters.
In addition, I need to create a new variable using the previous ones called list_items that changes its value according to the selected parameters, to send it I used a hidden input tag:

```
<input id="combo" name="combinaison" class="btn btn-success col-lg-12" type="hidden" value="test">
```

The variables are sent to `views.py` but the problem is that the value of the hidden input doesn't changed, it always shows the default value. I tried using:

```
document.getElementsByName("combinaison").value = list_items;
```

in the form but the value never changes.
Here is configuration.html

```
        {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% block body_block %}

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->

<script src="{% static 'staticfiles/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'staticfiles/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

<!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="staticfiles/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
<script src="staticfiles/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

<script src="staticfiles/vendor/app/app_config.js"></script>


            <!-- Begin Page Content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Grow In Utility -->
            <div class="col-lg-7">

              <div class="card position-relative">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Parametres</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                  <form action="/try" method="GET">
                       <script>
                       var i = 0;
                       var list_items = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
                       </script>

                       <h6>Nombre de classifieurs introduits</h6>

                      <select id="N_menu" onChange="Get_value('N_menu')" name="N" aria-controls="dataTable" class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm"><option value="100"></option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option></select>

                      <script>
                       var value_;
                       function Get_value(id){
                          value_ = document.getElementById(id).value;
                          return value_;
                       }
                      </script>

                      <br>
                      <br>


                      <h6>Choisissez les classifieurs</h6>

                      <select id="choix"  name="here" onchange="Save_choice()" aria-controls="dataTable" class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm"><option value="100"></option><option value="0">Naive Baise</option><option value="1">Arbre de décision</option><option value="2">Knn()</option><option value="3">Knn (nombre de voisins = 2)</option><option value="4">Knn (nombre de voisins = 7)</option><option value="5">Knn (nombre de voisins = 9)</option><option value="6">Knn (nombre de voisins = 10)</option><option value="7">Knn (nombre de voisins = 15)</option><option value="8">Knn (nombre de voisins = 20)</option><option value="9">Knn (nombre de voisins = 25)</option><option value="10">Knn (nombre de voisins = 30)</option><option value="11">Knn (nombre de voisins = 40)</option><option value="12">SVM (kernel = linear)</option><option value="13">SVM (kernel = poly)</option><option value="14">SVM (kernel = rbf)</option></select>
                      <script>
                            function Save_choice() {
                                if (i < Get_value('N_menu')) {

                                    val_idx = Get_value('choix');

                                    list_items[val_idx] = 1;

                                    i = i + 1;
                                }
                            }

                      </script>


                      <br>
                      <br>
                       <h6>Nombre de Classifieurs finale</h6>

                      <select id="NB_menu" onchange="NB_value()" name="Nb" aria-controls="dataTable" class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm"><option value="100"></option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option></select>

                      <br>
                      <br>
                       <h6>Choisissez l'algorihme d'optimisation </h6>

                      <select id="optim_menu"  name="algo" aria-controls="dataTable" class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm"><option value="100"></option><option value="0">Algorithme génétique</option><option value="1">Algorithme hybride</option></select>


                     <input id="combo" name="combinaison" class="btn btn-success col-lg-12" type="hidden" value="test">

                      <br>
                      <br>

                      <div class="col-lg-7" >

                      <div class="card position-relative" style="width: 60%;margin-left: 100%">

                          <button class="btn btn-success col-lg-12" id="btn" onclick="classification()">Enregistrer</button>


                          <script>
                              function classification() {
                                  $(document).ready(function () {
                                      document.getElementsByName("combinaison").value = list_items;
                                      $("#btn").click(function () {
                                          $.ajax({
                                              url: "/try",
                                              type: "GET",
                                              data: {
                                                  N: Get_value('N_menu'),
                                                  Nb: Get_value('Nb_menu'),
                                                  combinaison: Get_value("combo"),
                                                  algo: Get_value('choix'),
                                                  success: function () {
                                                      alert("Submitted succeffully");
                                                  },
                                              },
                                          });
                                      });
                                  });
                              }
                          </script>

                        </div>
                      </div>


                  </form>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Fade In Utility -->

          </div>

        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the function for views.py

```
def post(request):
    if request.method == "GET": #os request.GET():
        if (request.GET):
            data = request.GET.dict()
            N = data.get("N")
            combinaison = data.get("combinaison")
            Nb = data.get("Nb")
            choix_algo = data.get("algo")            
            return HttpResponse(combinaison)

    else:
        return HttpResponse("nope retry")
```

and this is the URL path in url.py

```
path('try', views.post),
```

Can someone please find where the problem is?

Comment: if you can calculate the values in the views, better to do so, and keep the form for user entry only

Comment: your javascript is all over the place, it's impossible for us to read and follow what's going on. The only thing I see is you set that value once (on document ready) and never again after that. But use your debugger, set a breakpoint in your javascript, step through it and check the various variables to see where they deviate from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of input in the wrong way
`document.getElementsByName("combinaison")` gives you a list of nodes you need to select the node and change the value

`document.getElementsByName("combinaison")[0].value = value_list`

the above line should solve your problem

Best practice never use className or any other attribute for change something like this try and use ID which will make sure to change only the necessary input

Comment: It didn't work, when i run it it still shows the initial value of the hidden input ("test")

Comment: You are trying to do same as [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jaswanth098/c85c456450aa73b36c5b88f7deb9309f) right?

Could you let me know how are you trying to verify the value is changed or not?

Comment: Now I have found the issue 
inside the classification function, you are again checking if the dom is ready or not
Now before making the backend call classification function is being called, but as you have written `$(document).ready(fn)` the call back function `fn` will only be called once the backend call is completed
If you remove the `$(document).ready(fn)` inside `classification` function, it will work fine
Eg: [example gist](https://gist.github.com/jaswanth098/c85c456450aa73b36c5b88f7deb9309f#file-function_change-js)